# SPL token transactions check

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, transactions, transfer, send-transaction

I figured out how to make my token and check incoming applications in the solana network with the usual transfer of solana. But how do I track an incoming transfer with a certain amount of my token to some address? Mn needs to make a code that will track the incoming transfer to a certain address and if the transfer really was and the amount in it corresponded (let's say 10 coins), then the system should issue a notification that the transaction has been accepted. Ideally, if the code is made in Python.

A corresponding gratitude for help is possible from me
My telegram for communication: @nikodim54
My discord: .nikodim10191537

Answer (score 1):

You can use the subscriptions API's `accountSubscribe` call with `jsonParsed` encoding to get a notification whenever your account is mentioned in a transaction: https://docs.solana.com/api/websocket#accountsubscribe

When you receive a notification, you'll get the new token amount in the account, which means that you'll have to keep track of the previous amount somewhere and see how much it's changed during every notification.

Comment: Hi! I don't really understand how to use what you indicated. can we write off in a telegram so that I can ask questions in a more detailed form? My telegram: @nikodim54

Comment: This is the place to ask questions in a detailed form! Feel free to expand on your question, or maybe better, ask another one

Comment: I understand. It's just that I'm actually a python developer and I didn't understand a little what you threw off. what programming language is it for, what libraries are needed. Could you, for example, make a sample code? And it is better if there is some kind of guide for the library on Python 

I offered to go to telegram, since I see messages there faster (not because I want to breed for some money, etc.).